# Can you delay the loading of an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have an accordion with an image that loads over the accordion. The image disappears when clicked revealing the accordion. This works correctly but as the page loads there is a moment when you can see the raw contents of the accordion before the image appears.
My script, hides the accordion, shows the image and then hides the image on click thus:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#theBomb").show();
    $("div#accordion").hide();
    $("#theBomb").click(function() {
        $(this).hide("explode", {pieces:100}, 1000,
          function(){
            $("div#accordion").show("blind");
            });
       }); 
     });
```

Is there any way I can stop the raw contents of the accordion appearing before the image loads?
I don't want to hide the contents of the accordion using css because if there is no Javascript active in the browser I want the reader to not see the image but see the contents of the accordion.

Comment: Hide it with css, then show it with css using noscript tags for those without javascript.

Comment: You can hide the *image* (not the accordian) with css and show it later with jQuery.

Comment: @ Hamaz Kubba. I believe this what I'm already doing, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('yourElement').delay(500).queue(function( nxt ) {
    $(this).load('yourpage');
    nxt();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe this fails the "no JS" condition. That is if JS is not active on the page then the contents will not load.